# Switcher discontinuous mode - potential EMI problem

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, emc, fcc

I need to design switching mode power supply with input voltage range of 25V-45V and output voltage 5V@2A.

Power supply must be ON while the system is in sleep mode(~1mA consumption). In that particular case switcher will be highly inefficient and will be working in dicontinuous mode. Since I need to pass both FCC and CE will that be a potential unresolvable problem? I have previous experience in designing BUCK converter but none of them had to go through certification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DCM is not necessarily less efficient --it depends on the controller.

If it is possible to raise the 5 V a little, you could add a linear regulator, limited to 1 mA in parallel with the SMPS. If the linear regulator regulates at (say) 5.2 V, the SMPS will see that VOUT is OK, and will fully switch off -- no switching cycles. When the load exceeds the 1 mA capability of the linear regulator, the SMPS will take over.

in addition, the inductor node will ring in DCM when the driver turns off -- put ~ 1kohm in parallel with the inductor to dampen this ringing. It will have a slight effect on efficiency though.

Comment: I have recently used a chip like the LTC3798 for an application with a wide input voltage and output current. The DCM detection circuitry worked pretty well and the design (which was very poorly laid out as it was my first SMPS) passed emissions testing. It was a 12V/2A output but I did have a static 1k load on the output to help reduce overvoltage.

Comment: Clever idea. When output is i.e. 5.2V switcher will see that the output is higher than it's meant to be so duty cycle will be 0%.

Comment: @scld What was your minimum output current?

Comment: Much more than yours as I had the 1k load, so 12 mA. I only had the 24W power supply because one of our configurations powered a second off board device. We passed at both high (~12W) and low (sleep with only 1k resistor static) load. However, the differences in transformer alone will make the results vary greatly.

Answer (score 2):

DCM is not that bad for EMC .Sure there is ringing due to the inductor and the parasitic capacitances ot the mosfet ,the diode , the coil inter turn capacitance and the PCB .This ringing can be damped with a small efficiency penalty .The frequency of this ringing is in my experience in the low MHz range .Is is easy to filter because its low enough that components like inductors and caps are reasonably ideal and its high enough that big bulky expensive LC values are not called for .Most importantly this resonance doesnt appear on radiated EMC plots like FCC A and B .If you are running cont mode the recovering diode or the high capacitance shottky can make stuff appear on radiated EMC .I dont exclusively do EMC for a living but I am sometimes called in to help when people have problems .In the last 18 years I can say that radiated is harder to pass than conducted .If people pass straight off I dont get to hear about it .So you may be better off using DCM than CCM .What I do when there is a low idle current need is ball cock the PSU between a upper and lower trip .I have linear post regulated when I have to have a close tolerance on the output volts and want to keep the trip points not too close together .There are other jargon words like burst mode that achieve the same thing .Another way that has and does work is to reduce the frequency in DCM .